The meaning of a representation in one-dimensional quantum mechanics
In many places, one reads about chosing a representation for studying a particular one-dimensional quantum system. Usual representations are the position representation, the momentum representation or the Bargmann-Fock representation. I m confused about the meaning of a representation itself in quantum mechanics. Does it simply mean to fix a concrete Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and concrete expressions for the position and the momentum operators $(Q,P)$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that, on the maximal domain of the commutator, one has $$[P,Q]=-i\hbar {\bf 1} ~?$$

Also, what do you mean with "one-dimensional quantum mechanics" exactly?

@TobiasFünke I mean if we are studying a particle moving on a straight line parametrized by the set of real numbers.

@user536450 Except that you aren't studying the motion of a particle. You are studying the absorption probability of a quantum of energy and momentum along a linear arrangement of detectors. For the free field the probability density of detection will be the same for every detector position and you will measure the same value for the momentum everywhere.

@FlatterMann Can every quantum mechanics problem in principle be solved in just the position space? i.e. suppose we are constrained / not allowed to use any other basis (momentum, Fock, etc), can we in principle solve every quantum mechanical problem in the position space, not worrying about how much more difficult / long the calculations will be?

@James My comment was about the actual physical phenomenology. What we are measuring are always position (and time) dependent energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge distributions. How we want to represent these at the level of the ensemble theory is irrelevant to nature. Personally I find that intuitive reasoning about quantum mechanics is best done in terms of energy and momentum because these are actual conserved properties. In comparison there is no such thing as a "position conservation law", i.e. the "particle picture" is rather unphysical and leads to remarkably poor intuition.

@FlatterMann thank you. I have heard it claimed that the exhaustive list of measurables in quantum mechanics are energy eigenvalue, position, linear velocity, and angular velocity (assuming mass, charge, etc, being held immutable). All other formulas e.g. $KE= \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ are to be derived from the above 4 basic measurables. Is this accurate, do you think?

@James The only "sharp" eigenvalues in quantum mechanics are those of ground states. Everything else is a meta-stable state with an energy distribution/decay time constant. Atomic states and their energies are also subject to external fields, so they are not really fundamental. Position is always position of the detector. Technically we are breaking Poincare symmetry with that one. I have no idea how you want to measure velocities in quantum systems. Those are emergent classical quantities.

@FlatterMann there is a post somewhere here that said that practically all operators in QM is based on position, momentum or spin, which is where I suppose I got the idea of "fundamental variables" from... Could you shed some light on this assertion, please?

@James I am "taking" a refresher course in QFT for fun on YouTube right now since I never had the chance to sit in an MIT class. The professor is going out of his way to introduce a momentum state aka plane wave as the "fundamental" state of the free theory. I agree that that is what one should start with since for plane waves the "un-natural" location component does not matter. The reason why WE care about localization so much is because we are localized ourselves. That's an emergent phenomenon that plays no role at the fundamental level.

In abstract terms the meaning of representation in these cases is the ordinary meaning of representation in the sense of representation theory. Concretely, you are representing the Heisenberg algebra on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.
...but indeed, effectively all this means is choosing

A particular Hilbert space, such as the space of square-integrable real functions (position representation, momentum representation) or the square-integrable holomorphic functions (Segal-Bargmann space, for the Segal-Bargmann-Fock representation).
Two concrete operators that are $Q$ and $P$ on that space with $[Q,P] = \mathrm{i}$.

